Restricting values of inputs passed into a reusable workflow
Is it possible to restrict the "allowed" values of a reusable workflow input in GitHub Actions?
This is currently possible in an Azure Pipelines template by using the values: field under a parameter.
Here is an example of that functionality from an Azure Pipelines template.
# azure-pipelines.yml

parameters:
  - { name: environment,  values: [dev, test, prod] }
  - { name: build_app,    default: true }
  - { name: deploy_infra, default: false }

stages:
  - stage: build_app
    displayName: Build Application
    condition: ${{ eq(parameters.build_app, true) }}
    jobs:
      - deployment: ${{ variables['System.TeamProject'] }}
        environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - script: echo build app

Is this functionality currently possible in GitHub Actions? My understanding is that it is not possible at the moment. Thanks.

I don't think there's a built-in capability to do this, you have to do it manually in a separate step.

GitHub Actions currently does not support this unfortunately.
You have to write a step for validate, for example:
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Validate environment input
        run: |
          if [[ ! "${{ inputs.environment }}" =~ ^(dev|test|prod)$ ]]; then
            echo "Error: Invalid environment. Must be dev, test, or prod."
            exit 1
          fi


workflow_dispatch trigger for regular workflows supports a choice input type that allows specifying a list of values for a pick-list used when triggering of a workflow manually on github.com UI.
Reusable workflows do to support this type. As per this doc:

on.workflow_call.inputs.<input_id>.type


Required if input is defined for the on.workflow_call keyword. The value of this parameter is a string specifying the data type of the input. This must be one of: boolean, number, or string


You can do the same in GitHub Actions.  Here is the sample code for that.
name: Deploy test services
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
       description: Target environment for the deployment
       type: choice
       required: true
       options:
         - dev
         - test
         - prod

After that you can continue with jobs, runner and other fields.
